# SwiftPages - gap between header and viewcontroller

Tags: swift

I try to use SwiftPages (https://github.com/GabrielAlva/SwiftPages) and it nearly works perfect. There is one thing that bothers me:

When the ViewController opens the first time, there is a little gap between the headers and the loaded ViewController. When I tap anywhere on the screen, it goes up and everything is fine:

[With gap on the left, without on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH1rj.jpg)

The code I have right now isn't too complicated:

```
let VCIDs : [String] = ["LoginViewController", "RegisterViewController"]
let buttonTitles : [String] = ["Login", "Registrieren"]


swiftPagesView.initializeWithVCIDsArrayAndButtonTitlesArray(VCIDs, buttonTitlesArray: buttonTitles)

self.view.addSubview(swiftPagesView)
```

Do you have any ideas, why that happens and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Seems like an issue in simulator - works fine on iPhone 6 :)